# How to get out of an infinite prompt loop when the prompt is assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, loops, prompt

Here's my code

```
function cc() {
  prompt("Choose Character") 
}

function cs() {
 var chars = setTimeout(function(){ cc() }, 3000);
  switch (chars) {
    case "spy":
    selectedspy()
    break;
    case "bulovian soldier":
    selectedbulovian()
    break;
    case "stonian soldier":
    selectedstonian()
    break;
    default:
    cs()
  }
}
```

it keeps getting stuck in an infinite loop of asking the prompt again. I feel like I'm making a simple mistake, but I couldn't figure what I needed to type into google to get the answer

Comment: `chars` is a timer handle. you want to evaluate the return value for `prompt`.

Comment: It's an infinite loop because your switch will always follow the default for the reason given by Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to do.

```
function cc() {
  return prompt("Choose Character");
}

function cs() {
  //This will only run the code once, if you wish to have a loop use setInterval()
  setTimeout(function(){      
    var chars = cc(); 

    switch (chars) {
      case "spy":
      selectedspy()
      break;

      case "bulovian soldier":
      selectedbulovian()
      break;

      case "stonian soldier":
      selectedstonian()
      break;

      default:
      cs()
  }

  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `setInterval`. The default case in the switch statement is to run `cs()` again, which would "restart" the timeout and show the prompt after 3 seconds again. It's a pretty common principle known as recursion.

Comment: Ah, that's correct I forgot he did that, thanks. @QuangdaoNguyen